# NLP process for combining common collocations

Tags: python, r, nlp, nltk, tm

I have a corpus that I'm using the tm package on in R (and also mirroring the same script in NLTK in python).  I'm working with unigrams, but would like a parser of some kind to combine words commonly co-located to be as if one word---ie, I'd like to stop seeing "New" and "York" separately in my data set when they occur together, and see this particular pair represented as "New York" as if that were a single word, and alongside other unigrams.

What is this process called, of transforming meaningful, common n-grams onto the same footing as unigrams?  Is it not a thing?  Finally, what would the `tm_map` look like for this?

`mydata.corpus <- tm_map(mydata.corpus, fancyfunction)`

And/or in python?

Comment: This is called collocation finding. Typical approaches first filter by POS tag, then compute mutual information and report all bigrams for which the MI exceeds some threshold. *Foundations of Statistical Natural Language Processing* has a section devoted to this problem.

Comment: Perhaps [Named-entity recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition)?

Comment: NLTK link to collocations: http://nltk.org/howto/collocations.html and the chapter mentioned by @larsman: http://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/promo/colloc.pdf

Comment: @amp, great link to the collocations page on NLTk !!! The howto pages  for NLTK is very much helpful to dev lazy to read the tutorials =)

Comment: Another approach is to use a full fledged syntactic parser (e.g., http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) and then recurse the parse tree looking at noun phrase nodes (NP). I found this approach most successful. More info here: http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/INT/INT7/paper/view/9253

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752356/create-a-dictionary-with-word-groups) and played around with collocations

This was the solution I chose to identify pairs of collocated words:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.collocations import *

text = <a long text read in as string string>

tokenized_text = word_tokenize(text)

bigram_measures = nltk.collocations.BigramAssocMeasures(tokenized_text)
finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_words()
scored = finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.raw_freq)

sorted(scored, key=lambda s: s[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Its giving the same score, irrespective of the words actually collocated or not