# Abbreviation detection

Tags: nlp

Under what field of study under natural language processing does abbreviation detection come? Looking for sources to learn abbreviation detection. I have considered Semantics, which basically detect synonyms. so i thought i might do multi-word semantics that would detect that "nlp" and "natural language processing" are similar. but i have found NO solution to do multi-word semantics.

**Note:** I know its really easy to down vote this question, but try to understand my problem. I have struggled for months now and any help is GREATLY appreciated...

Thankyou

Comment: I'm no expert in the field, but this sounds like an especially difficult problem, as it's highly dependent on both context and semantics.

Comment: no i dont think its really difficult, google, yahoo and bing are doing it

Comment: At a guess? Artificial Intelligence.

Comment: more over, its just like semantics which is really easy, i just don't know how to do multi word semantics

Comment: @ElliottFrisch what do you think natural language processing is?

Comment: [Compound term processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_term_processing)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch was that an answer to my post? or my comment?

Comment: To your post. I wasn't sure which "under" you meant originally.

Comment: can you please give me resources to learn it? i would still prefer multi token semantics

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from doing multi-word semantics. If you define context as the window of several words, you can easily collect and compare context similarities of both single words and multiword expressions.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi and do you consider Google, Yahoo and Microsoft aren't brilliant and they have armies of talented engineers?

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't get you @Chiron

Comment: this discussion is on MWE is getting way too wayward =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thankyou to all who helped me, I think i found an answer myself. I trust it because it is from a research paper by the person who invented the abbreviation expansion algorithm for Yahoo! and it also shows signs of artificial intelligence. Again, thankyou all.

To others in the same boat as me, here's the solution:

[SEO by the sea - How search engines might expand abbreviations in search queries](http://www.seobythesea.com/2009/10/how-search-engines-might-expand-abbreviations-in-queries/)

Answer (score 9):

(Automatic) Detection of abbreviations is also a major subproblem and task of sentence segmentation and tokenization processes in general, i.e.: disambiguate sentence endings from punctuation attached to abbrevations. 
Statistical methods (NLP) have been applied to detect and extract them successfully, mostly in a (semi-)supervised manner. E.g. the PUNKT system, which actually has been developed for sentence boundary detection, *is able to detect abbreviations with high accuracy*, *based on the assumption that a large number of ambiguities in the determination of sentence boundaries can be eliminated once abbreviations have been identified* ([Kiss et al. 2006. *Unsupervised Multilingual Sentence
Boundary Detection*](http://aclweb.org/anthology//J/J06/J06-4003.pdf)).

Now, before trying to modify the PUNKT system or similar, I was just trying to give a direction wrt. NLP-based abbr. detection. The system mentioned above, for example, applies techniques to measure collocational strengths between pairs of tokens, which can be two words, but also a word and some punctuation, treated as a token. It's all based on frequencies and probabilites, although the results in traditional collocational analysis' do allow for semantic research.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer @Nino it was great, but i have found an answer myself too. i'd rather accept that one. But thanks for your answer, i greatly appreciate your work being new to stackoverflow. i upvoted your answer, thankyou, and welcome to stackoverflow.

Comment: Somewhat related question touching on collocations: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20710593/583834

Answer (score 0):

You could start with simple rule-based solutions, e.g. look for patterns like "natural language processing (NLP)". I expect that given a large enough corpus, this could go a long way. And if you include a dump of Wikipedia...

Comment: Maybe you don't have to.

Comment: how do you define abbreviations?